# WinUI: How to reduce duplicate code when using lightweight styling?

Tags: xaml, winui-3, windows-app-sdk

I am using [lightweight styling](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/style/xaml-styles#lightweight-styling) to style a button:

```xaml
<Button ...>
    <Button.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPointerOver" Color="#48B2E9"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonForegroundPointerOver" Color="Black"/>
        ...
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

I would like to apply this styling to multiple (but not all) buttons.

Currently I need to copy and paste these `<Button.Resources>` to every button I want styled.

Is there a way to avoid this duplication?

I tried creating a style but couldn't figure out how to set resources in a style.

I guess I could create a control template, but that seems heavy handed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to style a built-in `Button`, you could consider creating a custom `Button` control which always have the resources applied to it.

Add a `UserControl` to the project (Project->Add New Item->User Control) in Visual Studio and replace the contents of the XAML file with something like this:

```
<!-- MyCustomButton.xaml -->
<Button
    x:Class="WinUIApp.MyCustomButton"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Button.Resources>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackgroundPointerOver" Color="#48B2E9"/>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonForegroundPointerOver" Color="Black"/>
    </Button.Resources>
</Button>
```

...and change the base class of the code-behind class accordingly:

```
// MyCustomButton.xaml.cs
public sealed partial class MyCustomButton : Button
{
    public MyCustomButton()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

You could then create instances of this `Button` in any other view as usual, e.g.:

```
<local:MyCustomButton Content="Click me!" />
<local:MyCustomButton Content="Another button..." />
```

Comment: Huh, in hindsight that seems somewhat obvious :P Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry About Misundrstanding

you cannot set Resources on a style definition.
so you must add a attached DependencyProperty to button and then set it on a style definition

see [this](https://www.reflectionit.nl/blog/2021/xaml-lightweight-styling-done-right)

Comment: Thanks for the fast response! Hm, adding a `<SolidColorBrush>` to a style gives me this error: `XamlCompiler error WMC0020: Cannot add 'SolidColorBrush' into the collection property 'Setters', type must be 'SetterBase'`. Are you sure this works with WinUI? :/